# Reputation for editing posts (+2) - no longer being given?

Tags: support

I've been editing posts recently, editing spelling, grammar and adding tags, but I don't seem to receive the +2 reputation any more.  I did see an SE announcement a while ago which explained the way reputation points are awarded is changing, but I don't have a link to it; this might explain it(?)

I had a look on the main SE site for guidance and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), which explains the +2 points is still awarded.  I'm rather puzzled now - is this still current policy or is the page out of date?

Thanks.

Comment: I think once you have 2000 reputation, you don't get +2 points for edit. I read it somewhere but I don't remember where.

Comment: @PS is right! The editor only gets +2 for each approved edit if his/her reputation is less than 2000 points!

Comment: OK, thanks for posting this

Comment: It is still rewarded for tag wiki edits up to 5,000 reputation points (at which point you can review others' tag wiki edits).